# I want to rewrite and redirect with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^site/story/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ story/$1/$2/$3/ [L,R=301]
```

I need `localhost/site/story/1/2/3`

to   `localhost/story/1/2/3/`
story is my file name and and site is folder name which i want to remove from url after that i need 3 parameter as get request.

Comment: not a issue.  i have url like a link and i want to change it as asked url... plz help me :(

Comment: i want to change localhost/site/story/1/2/3 url to localhost/story/1/2/3 url. but when i m apply above htaccess rule . it give me page not found error.

Comment: if you can help me on skype its much better for me. if you dont mind

Comment: this is not working on direct hit

Comment: no. this is not working in any case. i am new in htaccess and url rewriting